# Returning the Progress Status

Tags: c#

How do I return the status of the Progress from the below? Am I using the IProgress status properly? I had assumed there would be a Progress.report() function somewhere but it doesn't seem to be there.

```
        public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running Async Methods");
        AsynchronousMethods am = new AsynchronousMethods();

        Progress<int> p = new Progress<int>();
        Task ta = am.asyncMethods(p);


        while (!ta.IsCompleted)
        {
            // report progress
            // I would liek to return the Progress here. I am not sure how? 
            // there doesnt seem to be a P.result
        }
        ta.Wait();
    }


    public async Task asyncMethods(IProgress<int> pro)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1999; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I is {0}", i);
                pro.Report(i * 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: There's an event `ProgressChanged`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should handle the ProgressChanged event

```
Progress<int> p = new Progress<int>();
p.ProgressChanged += p_ProgressChanged;


static void p_ProgressChanged(object sender, int e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Progress :"+e);
}
```